# R and R-SQL API to execute SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r

For an assignment, I need to "use SQL to extract all tweets in twitter message-table under those 3 user ids in the previous step." I am currently confused with grabbing the tweet info from MySQL using the vector,x, in R.

I keep getting this error message, "Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  unused argument (c(18949452, 34713362, 477583514))."

```
    #use SQL to get a list of unique user id in twitter message table as a 
    #vector in R.
    res <- dbSendQuery(con, statement = "select user_id from 
    twitter_message")
    user_id <- dbFetch(res)
    user_id

    nrow(user_id)
    #randomly selects : use R to randomly generate 3 user id 

    x <- user_id[sample(nrow(user_id), 3, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL),]
    x

    res2 = dbSendQuery(con, statement = 'SELECT twitter_message WHERE 
    user_id =',x)
    tweets <- dbFetch(res2)
    tweets
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a vector, so you maybe you should use the `dbSendQuery` function in a loop. For each element in `x`, pass its value in your `dbSendQuery` statement. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am new to R would you have an example if how to do this?

Comment: I wrote a loop however it prints all tweets and not the one for the user_id of x if 
(user_id == x) 
  {
  print(tweets)
} else 
  {
  print("Tweets do not exist")
}

Comment: You'll need something like this:

`for (user_id in x) {  ... }`  between the parenthesis you can use the `dbSendQuery` results and append it into dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the help did something like this      res2 = "SELECT tweets FROM twitter_message WHERE user_id="

q1 = paste(res2,x[1],";",sep = "")        r1 = dbFetch(dbSendQuery(con, statement = q1))

Comment: That might work better!

 You can also convert x into a comma seperated value and use `WHERE user_id IN (`